# Undefined reference to curl

Tags: c, gcc, curl, codeblocks

I have to make a project using libcurl on Windows in Code blocks, but when I compile the "undefined reference to curl_global_init" etc. appears, what should I do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/types.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>
#include <string>

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
return written;
}

int main(void) {
CURL *curl;
FILE *fp;
CURLcode res;
char *url = "http://localhost/aaa.txt";
char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "C:\\bbb.txt";
curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) {
    fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/aaa.txt");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    fclose(fp);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's a linker error. Link with `-lcurl`.

Comment: Where write this `-lcurl` ?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is a linker error. The linker is not able to find the curl library. You need to specify paths where the linker would search for appropriate libraries at link time.

In this case (if you have installed lib curl in the standard lib directories e.g. /usr/lib, r /usr/local/lib) the following should work:

```
g++ you_file_name.cpp -lcurl
```

Otherwise you have to specify the path to the directory where the library can be found. for example:

```
g++ -L/curl/lib/dir -lcurl you_file_name.cpp.
```

When there are multiple libraries to link to, these things become complicated so it is a good idea to use a build-system such as CMake to assist in managing include-directories/library paths and various other things.

Comment: I have to select it in options, or write this line of code somewhere? :)